# Different clock cycles values for the same (repeated) code

Tags: c, profiling, microcontroller, cortex-m, nxp-microcontroller

I'm trying to profile some algorithms on my NXP LPC11U37H board (**ARM Cortex-M0**), as I want to know how many clock cycles are required to execute specific algorithms.

I wrote these simple macros to do some profiling:

```
#define START_COUNT clock_cycles = 0;\
Chip_TIMER_Enable(LPC_TIMER32_1);\
Chip_TIMER_Reset(LPC_TIMER32_1);\

#define STOP_COUNT Chip_TIMER_Disable(LPC_TIMER32_1);\

#define GET_COUNT clock_cycles = Chip_TIMER_ReadCount(LPC_TIMER32_1);\
myprintf("%d\n\r", clock_cycles);\
```

Basically, *START_COUNT* resets the *clock_cycles* variable, and enable and resets the counter, which is configured to count at the same frequency of the microcontroller (48MHz).
*STOP_COUNT* stops the timer, while *GET_COUNT* reads the timer value and prints it using UART (*myprintf()* is just a loop which sends characters via the serial port).

When I want to profile some algorithms, I just do something like this:

```
START_COUNT;
algorithm();
STOP_COUNT;
GET_COUNT;
```

Everything works, but it seems that something is wrong. Indeed I tried to profile this code:

```
START_COUNT;
for (volatile int i = 0; i < 1000; i++);
STOP_COUNT;
GET_COUNT;

START_COUNT;
for (volatile int i = 0; i < 1000; i++);
STOP_COUNT;
GET_COUNT;

START_COUNT;
for (volatile int i = 0; i < 1000; i++);
STOP_COUNT;
GET_COUNT;
```

And I got the following clock cycles values:

```
21076
19074
21074
```

That's something strange, as the compiler is configured to not optimize anything (GCC -O0, in Debug mode). Therefore, I checked the assembly code of the three code blocks, and they are exactly the same (except for memory addresses, etc. You can check it here: http://pastebin.com/raw/x6tbi3Mr - If you see some ISB/DSB instrunction, it's because I was trying to fix this behavior, but it didn't work).

Moreover, I disabled any interrupts.

I wonder what's the problem. Is there something that I'm not considering?

Comment: @MartinJames I forgot to specify it, but interrupts are disabled. I edited my post.

Comment: Compiler optimizations (unlikely)? But anyway, have a look at the generated assembly code.

Comment: @MichaelWalz I did. Indeed, I posted the link to it. Anyway, there is nothing special, as the three code blocks are the same...

Comment: @MikeDunlavey What do you mean? Can you elaborate? However, the instructions are in Flash, while the rest is in the SRAM.

Comment: I would not start and stop a timer. I would let it free run throughout the test, reading it once at the start and once after each test. You can then easily get the elapsed count with subtractions, and report afterwards. But anyway, I believe that processor has a **non-maskable interrupt** which might explain your timing discrepancy.

Comment: @WeatherVane The only non-maskable interrupt is handled by the NMIHandler, which is a while(1) loop. Since my program executes normally, I guess that this is not the cause.

Comment: I would look at alignment too.  the instructions are going to be fetched in groups on some alignment, for example maybe 8 words at a time.  if one loop is in three fetch lines and the other in two for example there are fewer bus cycles.  if instead of having the loop there between the timer calls, call the same function, does the time change for three calls to the same function?

Comment: you do understand since we started using pipelined processors you cant really do what you are trying to do.  it is not deterministic really and often not repeatable when you get into a real application.  change one line of code, add one nop to your bootstrap and you can change the amount of time something takes in either direction by as much as 10 to 20% (or as little as no change at all)

Comment: The TRM doesn't mention what the native read size of the flash might be (it could be buffered to satisfy the M0's 4-byte instruction fetches), but it's interesting to note that the middle loop fits inside a single 16-byte-aligned block, whereas the other two both just cross 16-byte boundaries.

Comment: I dont think the trms do, I think you have to have access to the design to see how they fetch for that design...and then of course outside the arm core the chip vendor can do whatever they want and take as much time as they want. so you would need access to that as well to see what is really going on.  you can add nops and play with alignments and number of instructions, etc to kind of get an idea but not the whole picture

Comment: that brings up a good point though, also try running these tests from sram instead of flash and see what you see

Comment: No guarantees, but will see if I can do a quick demo in an answer.   Note for example for this part you are using the FLASHTIM setting.  at 48MHz you need a setting of 3, which means the flash takes 4 clocks to access, basically it is running at 12Mhz, so granted there are other cycles but you are likely spending most of your time waiting on the flash to feed instructions, with no optimization and a loop like you have there are more memory accesses, but those I think keep up.  so for example if the arm were running at or under 20mhz, you might perform the same (if mostly bound by fetching)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Okay had some fun, made a simple example for you.  First off, every year goes by and new developers come along that don't know who Michael Abrash is, the world has changed yes, the tools are better, hardware, lots of folks that can tune things.  But the zen of assembly language is IMO very relevant, particularly this question.

https://github.com/jagregory/abrash-zen-of-asm

the 8088 was old news when the book came out and performance tuning on it today is even less relevant.  But if that is all you see in this book you are missing out.  I used what I learned there below and use it every day beating up on logic, chips and boards...making them perform and/or making them break.

And the point of this answer, is not necessarily to show how to profile something, although it will, as you are also already profiling something.  But it helps to show that it is not as straightforward as you would expect, there are factors other than just the C code you have written.  Placement of the C code in flash, flash vs ram, wait states or not, prefetch if you have it, branch prediction if you have it, all make a big difference.  I might even demonstrate the same sequence of instructions with a different alignment change the results.   Be happy you don't have a cache on the cortex-m0, that takes chaos and squares it...

I have NXP chips here somewhere, and I have at least one cortex-m0+ nearby, but chose a cortex-m0 from st.  STM32F030K6T6 as it was already wired up and ready to play with.  has a built in 8Mhz oscillator and a pll to multiply that so first play with 8Mhz then with 48.  It does not have the four different wait states as your chip, it has two choices, less than or equal to 24Mhz or greater than that (up to 48).  But it does have a prefetch, which yours may not have.

You might have a systick timer, something the chip vendor can choose to compile in or not.  They are always at the same address (in the cortex-ms so far if present)

```
#define STK_CSR 0xE000E010
#define STK_RVR 0xE000E014
#define STK_CVR 0xE000E018
#define STK_MASK 0x00FFFFFF
    PUT32(STK_CSR,4);
    PUT32(STK_RVR,0xFFFFFFFF);
    PUT32(STK_CVR,0x00000000);
    PUT32(STK_CSR,5);
    //count down.
```

PUT32 is an abstraction, long story wont get into it here

```
.thumb_func
.globl PUT32
PUT32:
    str r1,[r0]
    bx lr
```

now add a test function

```
.align 8
.thumb_func
.globl TEST
TEST:
    ldr r3,[r0]
test_loop:
    sub r1,#1
    bne test_loop
    ldr r2,[r0]
    sub r3,r2
    mov r0,r3
    bx lr
```

the simplest one is to read the time, do the loop the passed in number of times, then read the time and subtract to get the delta in time. and return that.  shortly will add nops between the loop top and the subtract.

with the align I am forcing the start of the function:

```
08000100 <TEST>:
 8000100:   6803        ldr r3, [r0, #0]

08000102 <test_loop>:
 8000102:   3901        subs    r1, #1
 8000104:   d1fd        bne.n   8000102 <test_loop>
 8000106:   6802        ldr r2, [r0, #0]
 8000108:   1a9b        subs    r3, r3, r2
 800010a:   1c18        adds    r0, r3, #0
 800010c:   4770        bx  lr
 800010e:   46c0        nop         ; (mov r8, r8)
 8000110:   46c0        nop         ; (mov r8, r8)
 8000112:   46c0        nop         ; (mov r8, r8)
```

btw, thanks for asking this question, I didnt realize my example code for this chip, wasnt setting the flash wait states right for 48MHz...

so at 8mhz I can play with the four combinations, fast and slow flash setting with and without the prefetch enabled.

```
PUT32(FLASH_ACR,0x00);
ra=TEST(STK_CVR,1000);
hexstring(ra);
ra=TEST(STK_CVR,1000);
hexstring(ra);
PUT32(FLASH_ACR,0x10);
ra=TEST(STK_CVR,1000);
hexstring(ra);
ra=TEST(STK_CVR,1000);
hexstring(ra);
PUT32(FLASH_ACR,0x01);
ra=TEST(STK_CVR,1000);
hexstring(ra);
ra=TEST(STK_CVR,1000);
hexstring(ra);
PUT32(FLASH_ACR,0x11);
ra=TEST(STK_CVR,1000);
hexstring(ra);
ra=TEST(STK_CVR,1000);
hexstring(ra);
```

so the TEST function as written above using the 8mhz internal no pll.

```
00000FA0
00000FA0
00000FA0
00000FA0
00001B56
00001B56
00000FA2
00000FA2
```

and then add more nops in the test loop

```
add one nop
00001388
00001388
00001388
00001388
00001F3F
00001F3F
00001389
00001389

two nops

00001770
00001770
00001770
00001770
0000270E
0000270E
00001B57
00001B57

three nops

00001B58
00001B58
00001B58
00001B58
00002AF7
00002AF7
00002133
00002133

eight nops

00002EE0
00002EE0
00002EE0
00002EE0
00004A36
00004A36
000036AE
000036AE

9

000032C8
000032C8
000032C8
000032C8
00004E1F
00004E1F
00003A96
00003A96

10

000036B0
000036B0
000036B0
000036B0
000055EE
000055EE
00003E7E
00003E7E

11


00003A98
00003A98
00003A98
00003A98
000059D7
000059D7
00004266
00004266


12

00003E80
00003E80
00003E80
00003E80
000061A6
000061A6
0000464E
0000464E

16

00004E20
00004E20
00004E20
00004E20
00007916
00007916
000055EE
000055EE

no wait state speeds

0x0FA0 = 4000  0
0x1388 = 5000  1
0x1770 = 6000  2
0x1B58 = 7000  3

0x2EE0 = 12000 8

0x4E20 = 20000 16


slow flash times

0x1B56 = 6998   0
0x1F3F = 7999   1
0x270E = 9998   2
0x2AF7 = 10999  3
0x4A36 = 18998  8
0x4E1F = 19999  9
0x55EE = 21998  10
0x59D7 = 22999  11
0x61A6 = 24998  12

0x7916 = 30998
```

so for this chip the no wait states with or without prefetch is the same, and is linear as far as I tested. add a nop you add 1000 clocks.  now why is no nop which is a subtract and a branch if not equal 4 instructions per loop and not 2.  that could be pipeline or that could be the amba/axi bus, long gone are the days where an cpu bus is just an address and some strobes (okay the wishbone designs on opencores).  you can download the amba/axi stuff from arms website to see what is going on there, so this could be pipeline or this could be a side effect of the bus, my guess is pipeline.

now the slow flash setting is the most interesting so far.  the no nop loop is basically 7000 clocks instead of 4000 so it feels like there are 3 more wait states in there per instruction.  each nop gives us 1000 more clocks so that is okay.  until we go from 9 to 10 nops, that costs us 2000, then from 11 to 12 is another 2000.  so unlike the no wait state version this is non-linear, is it because the prefetching of instructions pushes across a boundary?

So if I take a detour here, and between the TEST label and the load of the time stamp into r3 I add a nop, that should also push the alignment of the back end of the loop.  But that doesn't change the time for 8 nops in the loop. adding a second nop up front to push the alignment also does not change the time.  So much for that theory.

switching to 48MHz.

```
slow, no prefetch
00001B56
00001B56
slow, with prefetch
00000FA0
00000FA2

9 wait states

00004E1F
00004E1F
00003A96
00003A96

10 wait states

000055EE
000055EE
00003E7E
00003E7E
```

no real surprise there.  I shouldn't run with the fast flash setting so this is slow with and without prefetch.  and the speeds are the same relative to the timer which is based on the clock the whole chip runs at.  and we see the same interesting case that there is a non-linear step in the performance.  Remember/understand even though it is the same number of clock cycles in this case this clock is 6 times faster, so this code is running 6 times faster than the 8MHz.  Should be obvious, but don't forget to factor that into profiling.

I guess the interesting thing is that with prefetch enabled we are getting the 0xFA0 number.  Understand that prefetching sometimes helps and sometimes hurts, probably not too hard to create a benchmark that demonstrates it helping and not helping or not helping in a linear way.  we don't know how this hardware works but if the prefetch is say 4 words, the first word is at the 3 wait states but the next three are at one wait state.  but what if my code is doing some hopping thing

```
b one
nop
nop
nop
one:
b two
nop
nop
nop
two:
```

and so on. not knowing how the hardware works each of those branch destinations would be 6 clocks to fetch with prefetch, they might only be 3 clocks without, who knows...like a cache there is that time penalty of the extra stuff you read and don't use.  does the cache hits outweight the stuff read and not used?  same here do the prefetch timing gains outweigh the prefetched stuff not used?

last thing before leaving you to it, if I take the code with zero nops, and there are many ways to do this, but if I just brute force it into sram in a self modifying code fasion (or bootloader fashion if you will) and then branch to it

```
    ra=0x20000800;
    PUT16(ra,0x6803); ra+=2;
    PUT16(ra,0x3901); ra+=2;
    PUT16(ra,0xd1fd); ra+=2;
    PUT16(ra,0x6802); ra+=2;
    PUT16(ra,0x1a9b); ra+=2;
    PUT16(ra,0x1c18); ra+=2;
    PUT16(ra,0x4770); ra+=2;
    PUT16(ra,0x46c0); ra+=2;
    PUT16(ra,0x46c0); ra+=2;
    PUT16(ra,0x46c0); ra+=2;
    PUT16(ra,0x46c0); ra+=2;
    PUT16(ra,0x46c0); ra+=2;
    PUT16(ra,0x46c0); ra+=2;

    ra=branchto(STK_CVR,1000,0x20000801);
    hexstring(ra);
    ra=branchto(STK_CVR,1000,0x20000801);
    hexstring(ra);

.thumb_func
.globl branchto
branchto:
    bx r2

00000FA2
00000FA0
```

this is at 48Mhz btw.  I get the 0xFA0 number we would see with no wait states and/or with prefetch on.  I didnt try any more experiments after this but I suspect running from ram will not have any cliffs in the performance it will be linear for a simple test like this one.  it will be your best performance.  but you dont have a lot of it usually relative to flash.

when you have chips like the one you have, and when you play with relative clocks.  In this case for example at 8MHz, we have a loop taking 0xFA0 or 4000 clocks.  500us.  at 48mhz we start at 146us and get up to 83us.  but that same 4000 clocks with no prefetch at 24MHz is expected to be 167us at 25Mhz 280us without prefetch, faster clock noticeably slower performance, because we had to add those wait states.  your chip with four different wait state settings, (or any of these microcontrollers with flash that cannot run the full range of speeds without wait states) when you are at the top clock rate of a wait state setting, and then just over the edge at the next wait state setting slowest clock for that setting there is a performance hit.  ideally to push performance (and not caring about power consumption and other issues) you want to be running at the max clock speed for the target wait state setting.

these cortex-m0's are about as simple as it gets, when you say use a cortex-m4, with i and d caches, a much wider clock range, a mini mmu I think and other things.  profiling becomes difficult to impossible, move the same instructions around in memory and your performance can change from not at all to 10 or 20 percent either way.  change one line of code at the high level or add a single instruction within the code, and again you can see anywhere from little to large changes in performance.  which means you cannot tune for this, you cant just say these 100 lines of code go this fast and then modify code around them and assume they will continue to go this fast.  putting them in a function doesn't help, that function moves around as well when you add or remove things in the rest of the program, changing its performance.  At best you have to do what I have demonstrated here and have more control exactly where that code is placed so that function is always there.  And that still doesn't give you repeatable performance on platforms with caches, as what happens between each call to that function affects what is and isn't in the caches and how that function performs as a result.

And this is assembly code, not compiled C that I tested.  The compiler adds yet another wrinkle to this.  Some folks assume that the same C code always produces the same machine code.  Certainly not true, first off optimization.  Also also understand that one compiler vs another do not generate the same code, or you cant assume that, gcc vs llvm/clang for example.  Likewise different versions of the same compiler, gcc 3.x, 4.x and so on, with the case of gcc even the subversions vary sometimes widely in performance with everything else held constant (same source and same build commands), and it is not true that newer versions produce faster code, gcc has not followed that trend, generic compilers don't work well for any particular platform.  And the things they add from one version to the next are not all about performance of the output.  Gcc being distributed as source with lots of build knobs you can make multiple builds of the same version of gcc, with different build options, and I would bet you could end up with different results in things built by those two compilers that report the same version, all other things held equal.

With experience it becomes sometimes quite easy to take the same code and make its performance change on the same hardware.  Or make tiny modifications that you wouldn't think would make a difference but do.  Or if you have access to the logic, you can create programs to perform a task that have significantly different performance times.  It all starts with a book like zen of assembly or some others to open your eyes to these simple things, fast forward 20 years with dozens of hardware performance gizmos, each one of them helping sometimes and hurting others.  As Abrash says in so many words sometimes you have to try something crazy and time it just to see, you may end up with something that performs much better.

So I don't know what your goal was with this microcontroller, but you will need to continue to re-profile your code as you go, do not assume the first time is the final answer.  Every time you change anything from any line of source code to the compiler options or version, there is a change the performance will change significantly.  Allow for a wide margin in your design, and or test and tune every version.

What you are seeing is not necessarily a surprise.  Again with Abrash, it could also just be how you are using that timer...Understand your tools and make sure your timer works the way you expect.  Or it could be something else.